# Finding the Limit of a Given Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

[image: Function h]

I'm taking precalculus lessons and I would like to seek some help.

As per the preceding lessons, we are to determine whether $h$ is *continuous* or not.

To do that we would need to do the following (let's call it *Algorithm L*):

1. Check if $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x)$ exists
2. Check if $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x) = h(0)$

As part of *Algorithm L* ...

*Calculate the right-sided limit*
$\lim_{x \to 0^+}h(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\sqrt{x + \pi}$.
Now, according to the website, $\sqrt{x + \pi}$ is *continuous* over the interval $x \geq 0$ and so, it says, $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\sqrt{x + \pi} = \sqrt{0 + \pi} = \sqrt\pi$.
How do we know that $\sqrt{x + \pi}$ is *continuous*? The website doesn't show any work and I was expecting *Algorithm L* to be (re)used here, but the website simply states (without explaining why) that $\sqrt{x + \pi}$ is continuous in the given interval.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It is the composition of $\sqrt x$ and $x+\pi$.

Comment: How does that answer my question? Do you mean that because $\sqrt{x + \pi}$ is a *composite function*, it has to be *continuous*?

Comment: It's a composition of functions that are themselves continuous (in the required regions), and that makes it continuous.

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is *not* continuous, is it?

Comment: @$\sqrt x$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: So, that means, the *continuity* of a function is only meaningful if we specify some *point* OR *interval* at/in which the action takes places. In my question we're focused on the point $x = 0$. Eureka! Now I get it, we're only interested in *one*, not *both* of the right and left sided limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the function $h(x)$ can be split into

$h_1(x)=\sin x$ where $x<0$

$h_2(x)=\sqrt{x+\pi}$ where $x\geq0$.

Since the point at $x=0$ belongs to $h_2(x)$, we only care about where $h_2(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$. However, $h_2(x)=\sqrt{x+\pi}$ is clearly continuous at all $x\in[0, +\infty)$. Hence, the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Your question was whether h is continuous at x= 0.  Yes, $\sin(x)$ is continuous for all x and particularly for x= 0.  That means that $\lim_{x\to 0} sin(x)= sin(0)= 0$ so that $\lim_{x\to 0^-} sin(x)= 0$.
y
Yes, $\sqrt{x+ \pi}$ is continuous for all $x\ge \ge 0$ and particularly is "continuous from the right" at x= 0.  That means that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sqrt{x+\pi}= \sqrt{\pi}$.

The two one-sided limits exist but are NOT equal so the answer to your question is "No, h(x) is NOT continuous at x= 0".

Comment: Gracias. My issue is simple. To determine whether $f$ is *continuous* at $x = c$ we have this elaborate algorithm and then, for me this is rather sudden, one step down in the algorithm, there's no need to check (apply the aforementioned algorithm) whether the subfunction is continuous or not.